# PHP array to json readable output

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, function

i have a php array

```
if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0)
{
    $status = "OK";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        $info[] = array( 
                'postDate' => $row[1],
                'vedioURL' => extractifrem($row[2]),
                'like' => $row[3],  
                'totalView' => $row[4], 
                'viewTime' => $row[5]                   
            );

    }

$output = array(
            'status' => $status,
            'result' => $info
        );
```

I want to print my result of $output as valid json readable.I am using this code but not work

```
$soutput = array();
foreach($output as $v) {
    $soutput[key($v)] = current($v);
}
echo json_encode($soutput, 128);
```

Comment: why dont' you use `echo json_encode($output, true);` directly

Comment: I need the formate as "status": "OK",
    "result": [

        {
            "postDate": "2013-08-27 13:16:35",
            "vedioURL": false,
            "like": "0",
            "totalView": null,
            "viewTime": null
        },
        {
            "postDate": "2013-08-27 13:16:36",
            "vedioURL": false,
            "like": "0",
            "totalView": null,
            "viewTime": null
        }]@SatishSharma

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do like this..

```
$soutput = array();
foreach($output as $k=>$v) {
    $soutput[$k] = $v;
}
echo json_encode($soutput);
```

Comment: It returns Warning: key() expects parameter 1 to be array and Warning: current() expects parameter 1 to be array

Comment: is there any way to do result format as 
 "status": "OK", "result": [ { "postDate": "2013-08-27 13:16:35", "vedioURL": false, "like": "0", "totalView": null, "viewTime": null }, { "postDate": "2013-08-27 13:16:36", "vedioURL": false, "like": "0", "totalView": null, "viewTime": null }]

Answer (score 0):

Use only json_encode($soutput, true) inplace of json_encode($soutput, 128);